# Array copying in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to save my _POST array to a _SESSION array so that I can use that in other pages of the website
when i do

```
$_SESSION = $_POST;
```

it didn't worked.

Also the following code also is giving a error and not copying it.

```
foreach($_POST as $element){
  $_SESSION[] = $element;
}
```

Comment: http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions/7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SESSION` can't handle numeric keys; it must be an associative array. I.e. if you do

```
$_SESSION[] = "foo";
```

like you do in your foreach-loop, it'll create a new numeric key like in any other array (e.g. `$_SESSION[0] == "foo"`), *but* PHP will skip the key when saving the session. You get an "notice"-level warning like "Skipping numeric key 0". So the next time the `$_SESSION` array is read, it won't contain any numeric keys.

So you must use a string index, like:

```
$_SESSION['POST'] = $_POST;
```

That should work.

You should also be able to do `$_SESSION = $_POST` and overwrite the entire `$_SESSION` array. Can't say why that doesn't work. But I can't see why you would want to do it either. If you ever want to use `$_SESSION` for anything else (like, actual session data), you can't have your code randomly overwriting the entire array with post data here and there. Better to just use a string index like above to store the post data.

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['POST']) $_SESSION['POST'] = array();

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION['POST'][$key] = $value;
}

var_dump($_SESSION['POST']);
```

Comment: so can't i store value in $_SESSION array directly? in this case we are storing an array.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php tells that we  can really copy value by using $array[] = value syntax.