# Store info from DB in _SESSION data

Tags: php

I'm grabbing user data from the database using:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT usernames FROM login.users WHERE emails = :email");
$stmt->bindValue(":email", $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

And other fields than usernames (I haven't gotten around to fixing specifically which ones I'll be using).

Since I'm grabbing one user's data, it should return a single row of data. Thus, I can use:

```
$data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

which will give me an associative array in $data. But how do I then transfer that to $_SESSION?

[Array copying in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135966/array-copying-in-php) gave me the idea to use:

```
$_SESSION[$index] = $data[$index];
```

Or similar, but how would I go about automatically finding what $index was?
I'd really like it if I could change the SELECT statement to include different columns without having to have `$_SESSION['columnname'] = $data['columnname']` for every single column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could store the whole $data in a single session variable:

```
$_SESSION['data']=$data;
```

Or you could do the following:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
    $_SESSION[$key]=$value;
```

Comment: Would I then retrive it using $_SESSION['data']['username']?

Answer (score 0):

Do not store DB info in sessions. Sessions are designed to make volatile data persistent. Data in a database is already persistent, so there is no need, and bad design to put database data in a session.

Comment: The user logs in to my site. The user is presented with their profile page, which has username, first/last name, profile picture etc. How am I supposed to propagate this information between pages, if not in _SESSION?

Comment: Or are you saying I should query the db every time?

Comment: You should query the db during every page request. What if the user logs twice in and changes his profile in 1 page?

Comment: I'm going to come up with both solutions and do some profiling to see what kind of overhead increase this makes. But you're right if there are any critical things, like bank balances, stored. Man, design docs sure would help sometimes.